# Checking a list for item via specified text /w Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Relatively new to jquery here. Basically, on the page startup, I have a list of elements being retrieved and I want to check if this list contains a "Body" element, and if it does then I want this item in the list to be set as selected.

I have tried this based on some code I pinched elsewhere, so I'm not sure whether the ".length" part is required or not, but neither seems to work.

```
var bodyName = "Body";

if ($('#pageAreaList li:contains(' + bodyName + ')').length) {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    //Other stuff
}
```

Here is where the list is populated.

```
 function BuildPageAreaListHtml() {
        $("#pageAreaList").empty();
        ResetEditor();

        $.each(areaList, function (key, value) {
            var pageArea = $("<li class='selectable'><span class='listItemTitle'>" 
            + value.Name + "</span> - <span class='comment'>" 
            + value.Description + "</span></li>");
            pageArea.data("id", value.Id);
            pageArea.click(OnPageAreaClick);

            $("#pageAreaList").append(pageArea);
        });
    }
```

EDIT: HTML as requested:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="label">Page Areas:</div>
<div><ul id="pageAreaList"></ul></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Inspecting the element of the body item.

```
<li class="selectable"><span class="listItemTitle">Body</span> - 
<span class="comment">Contains the main content on a page</span></li>
```

Comment: Provide your HTML also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQJBX/1/). Why do you say it doesn't work?

---

**(1)** If I look the line :

```
$(this).addClass("selected");
```

Maybe this line don't do the thing you expect. `$(this)` isn't the `<li>` who contains "Body".

To do this, you need something like

```
$('#pageAreaList li:contains(' + bodyName + ')').each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

---

**(2)** Are you sure the text is "Body" and not "body" ? `:contains` is case sensitive.

---

**(3)** In my opinion, it is easier to check it when you fill your list.

```
    $.each(areaList, function (key, value) {
        var pageArea = $("<li class='selectable'><span class='listItemTitle'>" 
        + value.Name + "</span> - <span class='comment'>" 
        + value.Description + "</span></li>");
        pageArea.data("id", value.Id);
        pageArea.click(OnPageAreaClick);

        // Added
        pageArea.toggleClass('selected', value.Name.indexOf('Body') >= 0);

        $("#pageAreaList").append(pageArea);
    });
```

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought of this (3). Will try it after lunch and let you know. Updated original post with inspected element of the body page area.

Comment: Tried this and the list didn't display at all. Must be doing something wrong somewhere else but I'm not at liberty to post any more code, thanks for helping though.

Comment: So the problem was that I was calling the method before the list had been initialized, marked as answer for being a better way of doing things anyway!